# Convert Swedish, Ukrainian and French texts in a Symfony application

Tags: php, symfony, encoding

I use Symfony 5.5 and PHP 8.2 in my project.

Users can upload CSV with customers data in different encodings like : 'UTF-8', 'ASCII', 'Windows-1251', 'Windows-1252', 'ISO-8859-1', 'ISO-8859-15', 'ISO-8859-5', etc...

In my loop, I call this function for each row, but sometimes I don't have the good encoding.

Code :

```
class Functions
{
    const UTF8 = 'UTF-8';
    private static array $encodings = [
        'UTF-8',
        'ASCII',
        'Windows-1251', 
        'Windows-1252',
        'ISO-8859-1', 
        'ISO-8859-15', 
        'ISO-8859-5'
    ];

    public static function trimAndLower(): Closure
    {
        return static function ($value) {
            return strtolower(trim($value));
        };
    }

    public static function trimAndUtf8Encode(): Closure
    {
        return static function ($value) {
            $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($value, self::$encodings, true);

            if ($encoding === false) {
                $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_list_encodings(), true);
                array_unshift(self::$encodings, $encoding);
            }

            if ($encoding === false) {
                throw new Exception('Could not find encoding');
            }

            $convertedValue = mb_convert_encoding(trim($value), self::UTF8, $encoding);

            if ($convertedValue === false) {
                throw new Exception('Could not convert encoding');
            }

            return mb_strtoupper($convertedValue);
        };
    }
}
```

I think the `$encoding` order is important.

Thank you for you help,

Comment: `mb_detect_encoding()` is pretty much useless. Detecting encodings reliably normally needs human inspection and/or complex dictionary lookups. Your best chance is to do what LibreOffice Calc does: prompt the user and display a preview.